# Appropriate Data Structure for Vehicle parking system

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm developing vehicle parking system java application. The  application  should  keep track  when the  car entered  in  the  parking, when the  car left  from  the  parking, the  status  of parking,  whether  it  is full  or not. The  application  should  also  check  the  remaining  capacity  of cars  to  be  parked  in  the  parking. 
So, i want to ask what data structure should i use for the particular problem?

Note : Queues cant be used because they are based on First in and first out. So, car entering the parking lot first my not leave first. So, please suggest me an appropriate Data Structure for the particular situation.

Comment: linked list will be good tthen

Comment: @emotionlessbananas: Probably not. Linked lists are about the worst data structure in the universe. They are cumbersome to handle, They require extra storage for the links. They are slow because thay cannot be cached efficiently. There are some very spacific cases where linked lists make sense but this is most probably not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate container for storing the cars would be a `Set` because:

- There is no specific order of the elements (cars).
- Each car can be in the parking only once.

Other containers have special properties that are not required here:

- List: Ordering of elements (probably) not useful here.
- Queue: Next element to be deleted is not necessarily the first that has been added.
- Stack: Next element to be deleted is typically not the last that has been added.

Java provides different implementations of `Set`s. From a performance point of view, the `HashSet` implementation would be a good choice here because it has constant time complexity for the operations `add`, `remove`, `contains` and `size` which you will probably need .

Comment: That would make sense if you register the cars identified by an id. I guess that is too much and at least not part of the problem description. I think the cars should stay anonymous and only the count matters.

Comment: @Jan The problem said that the app had to keep track of when the cars entered and exited the lot - presumably for billing.

Comment: We can presume a lot here and the problem description is theoretical. I just wanted to point out that a set needs identifiable elements. A use case where two cars enter the system at the same time and time is the only attribute available for identification, what would happen to the element in the set?

Comment: @Jan: The identifier of a car does not have to be persistent. It could be a temporary id that is assigned when the car enters and is only valid until the car leaves. If the same car enters another time, it will probably get  assigned a different id. Aside from that, I have added an explanation for why the `set` is better suited here than other containers.

Comment: @FrankPuffer what about the map ds for this case?

Comment: @hemc4: You use a map if you like to map some key to some value. What is the key and what is the value here?

Answer (score 0):

There is no ready made data structure for your use case. You have to implement your own. Consider this code as a starting idea:

```
class ParkingSystem {
  List<Car> parkingCars;
  void onEnter(){
    Car car = new Car();
    car.entered = new Date();
    parkingCars.add(car);
  }
  void onLeave(Car car){
    parkingCars.remove(car)
  }
  int getCapacity(){
    return this.parkingCars.size();
  }
}
class Car {
  Date entered;      
}
```